# Rails, SQL - perform a Count and Select in a single query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Is there a way to do a single query to do both a select and a count, and get back an array with the two values? For example:

```
posts = Post.where(category = ?, 'somecategory').limit(10)
count = Post.where(category = ?, 'somecategory').count
```

Edit:

```
data = Post.find_by_sql(["SELECT count(category) AS total_count, * FROM posts WHERE category = ? GROUP BY posts.id LIMIT 10",'somecategory'])
```

Comment: No, with Active Record DSL you can't

Comment: Ahh okay. Do you mind helping me with what I added? I'm getting the posts back as an array, but the total_count is ending up in each array and is always one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work:

```
data = Post.find_by_sql(["SELECT count(*) OVER (), p.* FROM posts p WHERE category = ? GROUP BY p.id LIMIT 10",'somecategory'])
```

the issue with this though, is that it puts the count in each post. So to get the count you would have to do:
`count = data.first.count`. If anyone stumbles upon this, I think that this will probably be your next destination: [Rails, how to sanitize SQL in find_by_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145645/rails-how-to-sanitize-sql-in-find-by-sql).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
Post.where('category = ?', 'somecategory').select('id, count(id) as total_count').group(:id).limit(10)
```

The single query returns an array of Post objects with **total_count** as their attribute.

Comment: I'm only getting 1 returned when I try this. I'm also trying to do a full select, so it would be something like `Post.where('category = ?', 'somecategory').select('*, count(*) as total_count').group(:id).limit(10)`. On a side note, this is nice little hack to add a column that doesn't need to be in the DB  - without having the do something like `as_json.merge!`